# How can I summon boats with different types in 1.15?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to create a carousel on my minecraft spigot (paper) server, which runs version 1.15. For this I want several different boats to float in mid air. So far I've got it working just fine. They even move as planned.

[image: Minecraft boat carousel]

However, I can't get the command working to summon *different* boat types.

I've tried several approaches, but they all seem not to work. I only get normal oak boats. My original command summons invisible armor stands with boats on top of them to make them float in mid air. But even summoning single boats doesn't bring me colored boats...

`/summon boat ~ ~ ~ {type:"birch"}` = Oak boat. Same with Jungle, Spruce, etc.

To rule out plugin errors I've overridden the command with `/minecraft:summon`, but the result is the same. (This forces the server to use vanilla commands, regardless of what plugin or mod tries to override it.)

How can I summon boats of different wood types?

Answer (score 0):

Capitalisation matters: It's "`Type`", not "`type`".

Source: https://minecraft.wiki/w/Boat#Entity_data ([archive](https://minecraft.wiki/w/index.php?title=Boat&oldid=1555344#Entity_data))